# more filters in Numerictextbox with kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a nummericTextbox in Kendo, like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
        <label>Tonen vanaf verschil </label>
        <br />
        @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox()
                                    .Name("SignalThreshold")
                                    .Value(0)
                                    .Step(10)
                                    .Min(0)
                                    .Events(e => e.Change("FilterThresholdChange"))
                                 .Format("##.00")
        )
```

So you have a `FilterThresholdChange`

and that function looks like this:

```
function FilterThresholdChange() {
        $('#overzicht-grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({
            operator: function (task) {
                var thresholdAmount = $("#SignalThreshold").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();

                if (thresholdAmount == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return (task.Verschil >= thresholdAmount || (task.Verschil < 0 && task.Verschil <= thresholdAmount * -1));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But that is a filter for euro,

And I also want a filter for percentage.

So is it possible to make a second filter for NumerictTextbox?

Thank you

Comment: Are you want both currency & percentage filters with same `NumericTextBox` helper, or make them separately for each helper?

Comment: The same Numerictextbox. I also made a post here, Where I describe the hole scenaria. Because I am using a Kendo switch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734399/how-to-show-percentage-with-kendo-switch-with-jquery